# PDO exception when try delete statuses

Tags: database, comments

I am getting a PDO exception error when I am trying to delete a status update. There is a sub module in [statuses](http://drupal.org/statuses) module, Statuses Comments Flag Integration; maybe it has some problem.

(In addition I am getting the _The module providing this flag wasn't found, or this flag type, fbss_comment, isn't valid_ error when trying to enable ***"comments like flag"***.)

Maybe I have to create a table. How do I create the table for this error? I know I have to run an sql query in phpadmin.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project_kickstart.flag_content' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM {flag_content} WHERE (content_type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (content_id IN (SELECT fbss_comments.cid AS cid FROM {fbss_comments} fbss_comments WHERE (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) )) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => fbss_comment [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 50 ) in fbss_comments_flag_statuses_delete() (line 20 of C:\Users\taimoor\Sites\devdesktop\project_kickstart\profiles\project_kickstart\modules\contrib\statuses\submodules\fbss_comments\fbss_comments_flag\fbss_comments_flag.module)

I have mentioned the additional error because i think they are related.

Comment: Please share which version of Drupal, Flag and fbssc you're using, because fbssc isn't available for D7 and flag_content table was used in D6? Try running update.php to see if that help.